# buffering points and overlapping them to calculate areas

Tags: buffer, overlay, geopandas

Say if I have some drivers' geolocations, they are points with lat/lon, I have two tasks for this data.

> - I want to calculate each of the drivers' driving areas by buffering those points (for example, with distance = 10) and overlapping them
> - After that, I also want to obtain the shared areas between each of the drivers based on the buffered areas calculated from the above

I made some data for those tasks:

```
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# import libraries
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# df to gdf
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
d = {'driver':['a','a','a','a','a','b','b','b','b','b','c','c','c','c','c'],
     'lat':[41,46,39,43,51,43,45,58,49,42,40,42,48,50,46],
     'lon':[-78,-73,-66,-75,-80,-78,-70,-76,-68,-80,-72,-60,-62,-74,-72]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(df.lat, df.lon))
gdf.head()
```

Specifically, my questions are: 1. how to calculate driving areas for the driver a, b, and c using buffer (for example, distance=10) and overlay? 2. how to calculate the overlapping areas between driver a and b, driver a and c, and driver b and c based on their driving areas from last step? Much appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried? The geopandas website has informative docs about both buffers and overalys. What wasn't clear about them?

Comment: Yeah, I tried both geopandas and shapely. But their examples are for individual point or two points. Here I have a dataframe with multiple rows, I do not know how to write a loop to iterate each row. An example of how to implement it would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: show us what you tried and exactly what your expected output is

Comment: could you link to the geopandas docs you looked at?

Comment: Of course. I was looking at the example using "unary_union()" here https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual.html (you can search for unary_union() on that page).

Comment: Here is my idea (correct me if I misunderstand the process): 1. First, with this geo-point data, I can get driver a's five points and buffer each point with 10 (meters or miles, it dependents on the projection) and create a polygon based on the buffered area. I do the same thing for driver b and c. This will be their individual driving area.

Comment: 2. With each individual polygon for driver a, b, and c, I overlap a and b, a and c, b and c, this will be there overlapped driving areas. Am I make it clear enough?

Comment: you need to look at the geopandas docs. they are geared towards work flows that operate on the entire (geo)dataframe

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213456/discussion-between-neo-and-paul-h).